# How to use two different scopes in thymeleaf th:with assignment

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have a following construct that occurs within a form:

```
<tr th:each="team : ${teams}" th:with="checked = *{#lists.contains(userTeams, team.internalId)}">
```

where:

- userTeams- List - field within form backing bean - not null
- teams - List - global model attribute
- team.internalId - String, not null

results in:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 7): Property or field 'internalId' cannot be found on null
```

version 2

```
<tr th:each="team : ${teams}" th:with="checked = *{#lists.contains(userTeams, __${team.internalId}__)}">
```

and the exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 7): Property or field 'b' cannot be found on object of type 'x.domain.UserWrapper' - maybe not public?
```

team.internalId is expected to be "b-123" String, hier, though, it is evaluated as an aritmetic operation, thus the field 'b'

How can I correctly pass the 'team.internalId' value to the contains() method?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Property or field 'internalId' cannot be found on null` implies that your `team` variable is in fact null, which would imply that there is a null element within your `teams` list.

If you're not expecting your `teams` to have any null items, you need to look at what's populating it to see how that null is getting there.

If you are expecting your `teams` to have null items, then either

1. You want to use the [Safe Navigation operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation) like `team?.internalId`. This will not give an error on null, but will just propagate the null value. Or,
2. You don't want to handle null values at all, in which case you should skip them, like this:

   ```
   <tr th:each="team : ${teams}" th:if="${team != null}" th:with="checked = *{#lists.contains(userTeams, team.internalId)}">
   ```